# How to execute If condition in excel with Null Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am facing the problem to read the null value in the excel with the given formula the result is coming out to be Valid wheras the result should be coming to Invalid.

| B2 | C2 | IF((B2<=C2),"Valid", "Invalid" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | Valid |
|  | 0 | Valid |

Comment: Do those cells actually contain the word Null, or are they really empty?

Comment: they are empty, Null is not mentioned

Comment: An empty cell and 0 will be treated as equivalent. If you don't want that, then test for the empty cell explicitly. Are you saying that *both* of those rows should be invalid? What if **both** cells in a row were empty?

Comment: @s.roy_29 Your results are okay. null/blank cells represent `0`. So `0=null` result true.

Comment: Both the rows should come as invalid but instead its coming Valid.

Comment: And what if both cells are empty?

Comment: They are  empty null word is not in the database, I have edit the question to give clarity